# MySQL SUM ( Query works but returns unexpected results )

Tags: mysql

I am performing a MySQL Query on two tables

keyword_stats

```
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| keywordid   | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| campaignid  | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| clicks      | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| impressions | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| cost        | decimal(10,2) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| conversions | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| timestamp   | timestamp     | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| statsdate   | date          | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

AND

Keywords table

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| clientid   | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| campaignid | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| keywordid  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| text       | varchar(125) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| status     | varchar(10)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

With the following SQL Query

```
SELECT
    k.status, statsdate, 
    SUM( impressions ) AS impressions, SUM( clicks ) AS clicks, 
    SUM( conversions ) AS conversions, SUM( cost ) AS cost
    FROM keyword_stats
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    text,keywordid,status
                FROM keywords
            ) AS k USING (keywordid)
    WHERE 
       campaignid = 56486451
       AND statsdate BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND '2011-03-23'
       AND k.status = "enabled"
    GROUP BY keywordid
    ORDER BY conversions DESC, clicks DESC, impressions DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

With the results of

```
+---------+------------+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------+
| status  | statsdate  | impressions | clicks | conversions | cost      |
+---------+------------+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------+
| enabled | 2011-03-01 |    71256166 | 242079 |        4247 | 891572.71 |
| enabled | 2011-03-01 |        1101 |     10 |           1 |     43.19 |
| enabled | 2011-03-01 |         210 |      6 |           0 |     23.40 |
| enabled | 2011-03-01 |         331 |      4 |           0 |     15.29 |
| enabled | 2011-03-01 |         672 |      3 |           0 |     11.41 |
| enabled | 2011-03-01 |         486 |      2 |           0 |      8.93 |
| enabled | 2011-03-01 |         254 |      2 |           0 |      9.48 |
| enabled | 2011-03-01 |        2201 |      1 |           0 |      2.96 |
| enabled | 2011-03-01 |         581 |      1 |           0 |      3.25 |
| enabled | 2011-03-01 |         483 |      1 |           0 |      4.39 |
+---------+------------+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------+
10 rows in set (12.12 sec)
```

The query runs and performs as expected, except as you may see the first result contains unexpected results, since it is impossible for any keywords to have that amount of clicks, conversions or cost as a sum total I'm trying to figure where MySQL is combining the totals to achieve that result

EDIT ADDED KEYWORDID

```
+------------+---------+------------+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------+
| keywordid  | status  | statsdate  | impressions | clicks | conversions | cost      |
+------------+---------+------------+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------+
| 2147483647 | enabled | 2011-03-01 |    71256166 | 242079 |        4247 | 891572.71 |
|  101936939 | enabled | 2011-03-01 |        1101 |     10 |           1 |     43.19 |
|   23039553 | enabled | 2011-03-01 |         210 |      6 |           0 |     23.40 |
|  117364874 | enabled | 2011-03-01 |         331 |      4 |           0 |     15.29 |
|   18862051 | enabled | 2011-03-01 |         672 |      3 |           0 |     11.41 |
|   16695651 | enabled | 2011-03-01 |         486 |      2 |           0 |      8.93 |
|   14690232 | enabled | 2011-03-01 |         254 |      2 |           0 |      9.48 |
|   18046691 | enabled | 2011-03-01 |        2201 |      1 |           0 |      2.96 |
|   22232901 | enabled | 2011-03-01 |         581 |      1 |           0 |      3.25 |
|   15072731 | enabled | 2011-03-01 |         483 |      1 |           0 |      4.39 |
+------------+---------+------------+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------+
10 rows in set (11.99 sec)
```

Comment: can you add a keyword field and group by it as well? i want to see what is different between the sum totals...

Comment: It either "works" (performs as expected) or it doesn't. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keywordid` is a `PRIMARY KEY` in neither table.

Most probably, you have a `keywordid` with lots of records in both tables which results in a cross join on this `keywordid`.

Also note that, first, a `LEFT JOIN` is redundant in your query since your are filtering on `k.status`, and, second, `MySQL` is not that good in optimizing inline views.

Just use this:

```
SELECT  k.status, statsdate, 
        SUM( impressions ) AS impressions, SUM( clicks ) AS clicks, 
        SUM( conversions ) AS conversions, SUM( cost ) AS cost
FROM    keyword_stats
JOIN    keywords
USING   (keywordid)
WHERE   campaignid = 56486451
        AND statsdate BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND '2011-03-23'
        AND k.status = "enabled"
GROUP BY
        keywordid
ORDER BY
        conversions DESC, clicks DESC, impressions DESC
LIMIT   0, 10
```

Comment: The keywordid is prevalent in both tables (8,000) records in the keywords and 30,000 records in the keyword_stats table.

Comment: @nwhiting: do I get you right: you have `8k` records in `keywords` and `30k` records in `keyword_stats` sharing the same value of `keywordid`?

Comment: @quassnoi yes there are 8k keyword records in the `keywords` table with `30k` records in the `keyword_stats` table which have a corresponding `keywordid`.

Comment: @quassnoi I also ran the query you provided and while it ran faster it provided the same results.

Comment: @nwhiting: how many records with `keywordid = 2147483647` are there in each table?

Comment: @quassnoi - One as of now ... issue fixed, it was not the query which was causing the issue.

It turns out that the keywordid needed to be a larger value up to 30 which truncated the keywordid to a smaller value creating a large group of id's.

Which created the problem of when pulling the sum's for the stats total there where more records than expected. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the information for each day?  or do you need the data sum for all days?

If you want data for each day put "statsdate" in your group by expression.

Then, I thik that you don't need make a subquery. You can put the table name right in left join.

If you want the data for each "keywordid" put "keywordid" in the result fields. Status is not mandatory because always is "enabled"

Example:

```
SELECT
    keywordid, statsdate, 
    SUM( impressions ) AS impressions, SUM( clicks ) AS clicks, 
    SUM( conversions ) AS conversions, SUM( cost ) AS cost
    FROM keyword_stats
    LEFT JOIN keywords k USING (keywordid)
    WHERE 
       campaignid = 56486451
       AND statsdate BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND '2011-03-23'
       AND k.status = "enabled"
    GROUP BY keywordid, statsdate
    ORDER BY conversions DESC, clicks DESC, impressions DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```